# Converted tag synonym don't allow to filtering on converted tagged threads

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-synonym-process

Very recently the tag [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/products) *(plural)* has been converted to a synonym [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) *(singular)*.
*It is is not a real problem even if I was using it a lot more than the [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) (singular)*.

**But the problem is the search (or filtering threads):**
If I use [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/products) *(plural)* in search *(or as a filter)*, It doesn't display any related threads as it's auto converted to [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) *(singular)*. And the [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) *(singular)*, doesn't display either those threads.

> **So the issue *(the bug)*** is that all threads tagged with "products" **are not any more searchable *(or filterable)*** using "products" or even "product".

One of the main purpose of tags, is to be able to filter threads.

What I can do?
Do I have to convert the 687 threads where I have answered one by one to [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) *(singular)*?

Comment: 3,439 that show up in [product] seems okay -- that's 1,946 originally tagged product and 1,493 tagged products. Could you elaborate on what the 687 is you mention?

Comment: @JonClements Try that 2 filterings and you should understand: 1. [with "products"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bproducts%5D) and 2. [with "product"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bproduct%5D) … In both cases I get 6 threads. So yes I have 6 answer threads tagged with "product", but I have 687 answer threads tagged "products"… So those 687 threads should be filterable with "product" or either "products"… Since that converted tag, they are just lost from filtering on "product" or "products". I hope you understand now.

Comment: I've  merged products->product and kept the syn... you should get more what you're expecting now...

Comment: @JonClements Sorry last thing, On my profile I had the gold tag for "products", it has just desapeard… Is that normal… Do I should need to change manually all related threads from "products" to "product" to get one again? May be is it possible to merge all tagged threads with "products" to product" keeping the synonym redirection.

Comment: If you had gold for "products" then when the system next does the badge tags awarding - you'll get one for "product" same as you had for "products"... might take a little while though (can't remember exactly how often that process runs but it if it's not back within 24 hours, then let me know... but it *will* come back)

Comment: @JonClements Yes thanks… You are right it will take some time.

Comment: I'm not going to mark this with any status as although your immediate issue appears to have been fixed, there's still something iffy going on with synonyms for searching - I'm fairly sure it's come up before and animuson's (I think) has explained why but I can't find that right now... but it's a valid bug report (although a likely duplicate...)

Comment: @JonClements I didn't find any similar threads, but maybe yes and it will be a kind reminder for this bug like. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Looks like you got your badge back a few mins ago :)

Comment: @JonClements Thank you, really perfect. Does synonym conversion need always a manual merge from moderators, or this is going to be automated?

Comment: There's a bit of a difference between a merge and a syn. A syn. can be proposed and done by the community. There's obviously still a bit of a bug when that happens on large tags. A "merge" can only be done by mods as it effectively rewrites history - the tag "products" for instance, has right now, never existed - it's like "product" has always done so instead. That's not going to be automated  - it'll always require a level of "overview" and a human to "pull the trigger" if needs be.